# Switch case statements in dynamically typed languages

Tags: switch-statement

I wonder how dynamically typed languages behave when they found a matching case label. Will it continue evaluating the other label values that it hasn't yet compared? (to find duplicate case labels or type errors).

How do common dynamically typed languages behave there?

Comment: AFAIK, they just test the cases individuality, and in order till a match is found. Just like a big `if/else if/else`. This is the case in Scheme anyways. The compiler writer is allowed to optimize if possible though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only speak for JavaScript here, but JavaScript will search for a matching label by first checking that both operands are of the same type, then will check for value. If a match is found, the switch case will execute the statements associated with the labels and break out of the switch statement (if a break statement is found).

Example:

```
notANumber='0'

switch (notANumber) {
  case 0:
    alert("It's a number, Jim.");
    break;
  case '0':
    alert("It's a string, Jim.");
    break;
}
```

This will result in showing a popup saying `It's a string, Jim.`. It's actually not so different from a C-switch (sadly ;-)).

**EDIT**

The `===` operator is used here for comparison, which does not only test for value, but also for type. If the `==` operator would be used instead, the operands would only be tested for value (which would result in the first case being true).

Answer (score 1):

There are two well known approaches to switch, nothing to do with dynamic though as case labels are generally literals.

What happens depends on fall through.

Implicit fall through would execute all cases where there was a match in order of the cases in the code.

Explicit fall through would execute the first matching case and no other unless you explicitly jump to another case label which can be anywhere in the switch.

Comment: You are actually just describing C-based language behavior. Most dynamic languages have no concept of jumps or gotos.

Comment: No I'm not, dynamic is irrelevant.